# RxJava - Schedulers vs ExecutorService?

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java

I had a hunch that for highly computational, parallelized tasks in RxJava, a traditional `ExecutorService` would be faster than a `Scheduler`.

I had a theory that this code

```
Observable<MyItem> source = ...

source.flatMap(myItem -> myItem.process().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
.subscribe();
```

would run slower than this

```
final ExecutorService svc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1);
Observable<MyItem> source = ...

source.flatMap(myItem -> myItem.process().subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(svc)))
.finallyDo(svc::shutdown)
.subscribe();
```

I compared these two approaches with a typical parallel process I do at work, and I got the following results.

```
EXECUTOR

START: 2016-01-25T09:47:04.350
END: 2016-01-25T09:48:37.181
TOTAL TIME (SEC): 92


COMPUTATION SCHEDULER

START: 2016-01-25T09:50:37.799
END: 2016-01-25T09:54:23.674
TOTAL TIME (SEC): 225
```

So my rough testing has shown the traditional `ExecutorService` is much faster than a `Scheduler` for computation.

Is there a reason for these results? Are RxJava schedulers just not optimized for parallelization? I've gotten the impression that computation schedulers use lesser threads than Executors.

Comment: In neither case is it processing items in parallel. If you want parallel execution you should check out the experimental library [RxJavaParallel](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaParallel).

Comment: It's still a good question as to why `ExecutorService` is faster than `Schedulers.computation()`, though. I'm not qualified to answer that.

Comment: I think that project has been in limbo for a year, mostly because the RxJava devs can't prioritize their time on it right now.

Comment: David Karnok commented on my [RxJava parallelization article](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html) and said "If you have 8 cores, this will only use 5 of them. If you have 4 cores, two groups will share the same core." I'm curious as to why RxJava Schedulers are so conservative about creating threads and utilizing processors.

Comment: Actually, it is processing items in parallel because the subscribeOn() occurs in a flatMap().

Comment: Ah, I misread the parens, sorry. You're right.

Comment: I guess because `Schedulers.computation` uses `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, threadFactory)` for each worker.

Comment: Revisiting this, that is interesting. According the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool(int)) then that means there is only one thread? My tests indicate there is more threads than that, just not enough by some standards I've seen. Its interesting there is a delay factor in the `Executor` too. What drives the optimal number of threads?

Comment: FYI, I blogged about this topic a few months later. http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/rxjava-maximizing-parallelization.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did several tests and discovered that creating your own `ExecutorService` can in fact increase parallelization performance. [I wrote a blog post on it here](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/rxjava-maximizing-parallelization.html).

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Schedulers.computation()`, all the events are handled in the same thread. You can refer to the source code `CachedThreadScheduler.java` and `NewThreadWorker.java`. The benefit of this implementation is that if eventA is emitted after eventB, then eventA will be handled after eventB.

When you use `Schedulers.from()`, the events are handled in different threads.

Comment: Just checked the computation() scheduler - still got parallel execution. [The docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#computation--) for RxJava2 say there are as many single-threaded instances as there are CPUs.