# Rxjava schedulers computation behavior

Tags: rx-java2

I noticed a strange behavior in my rxjava workflow.

The problem is when I combine long data streams with short ones ( depending on what getEntries() returns).

The long streams take minutes, the short ones up to a couple of seconds.

Usually, even if the short subscription starts after the long one, it gets onComplete before. However, in about 1 of 4 or 5 attempts, the onComplete for the short stream is received right after the one of the long one.

I suspect this is due to the computation scheduler that chooses to schedule the onComplete on the rx thread kept busy by the long subscription. What boggles me is that the other 7 rx computation threads (8 core machine) threads are doing nothing.

I tried with a different thread on each subscription and it works as expected every time

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

.observeOn(Schedulers.from(executor))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor))
```

Code below

Service

```
public Flowable<E> entryFlow()
{
    return Flowable
        .fromIterable(getEntries())
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .concatMap(this::transformEntry);
}

Flowable<E> transformEntry(E entry)
{
    return Flowable.just(entry);
}
```

transformEntry may be overriden in some cases, but in my trial runs it was always a single element so I'm not sure if concatMap plays a role in this.

Consumer

```
service
      .entryFlow()
      .doOnCancel(this::onCancel)
      .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .subscribe(
                this::onNext,
                this::onError,
                this::onComplete);
```

I took a look at this question [RxJava - Schedulers vs ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997292/rxjava-schedulers-vs-executorservice) and the referenced blog post and comments, but it's still not clear on why this happens and furthermore the frequency (~ 1 in 4 times).

Would appreciate some ideas on this.

Thank you

Comment: Workers are assigned in a round robin fashion so if one is still busy servicing an earlier flow, it may hold up other flows. This is especially true if you are doing blocking work on the computation scheduler instead of on the io scheduler.

Comment: Hi @akarnokd . So what you're saying is that the 'free' threads don't have priority over busy ones. Is my understanding correct? Also, if by blocking you mean thread sleep / waiting for io that's not the case. The thread keeps the core by doing work, just that it may take time (minutes).

Comment: Each worker handed out uses a dedicated thread, multiple workers can end up with the same dedicated threads. This improves the thread-locality effects for typical, independent and non-blocking computation work. In contrast `Schedulers.from()` are not confined to a single backing thread and they are free to pick up tasks submitted by various operators on any thread that is available.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.